# Получение символа из его кода в Java по аналогии с String.fromCharCode в JS

Tags: javascript, java

Нужно переписать данный код с JS:

```
function deobfuscate(string) {
    var arr = string.split('.');
    var result = '';
    for (index = 0; index < arr.length; ++index) {
        if (arr[index]) {
            result += String.fromCharCode(Math.sqrt(arr[index]));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

На Java. Что я уже сделал:

```
private String deobfuscate(String obfuscate) {
    String[] numbers = obfuscate.split("\\.");
    String result = "";
    for(String number : numbers) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
        int sqrtnum = Math.sqrt(num);
        String schar = ???;
        result += schar;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Что писать вместо `???`? Я так понял, в JS коде число переводится в Unicode символ, но как это сделать в Java?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2946081/2881286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Метод `Math.sqrt` возвращает `double`, так что должно быть:

   ```
   double sqrtnum = Math.sqrt(num);
   ```
2. Получить символ из его кода можно простым приведением типа:

   ```
   char c = (char)sqrtnum;
   ```

С учетом использования `StringBuilder` вместо конкатенации строк получается так:

```
private String deobfuscate(String obfuscate)
{
    String[] numbers = obfuscate.split("\\.");
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(numbers.length);
    for (String number : numbers)
    {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
        double sqrtnum = Math.sqrt(num);
        char c = (char)sqrtnum;
        result.append(c);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Перевод ответа [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2946081/2881286)

У класса *String* есть [конструктор принимающий `int[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28int[],%20int,%20int%29) (добавлено с Java 1.5):

```
public static String fromCharCode(int... codePoints) {
    return new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);
}
```